# Hyperledge gateway v2 failure - gRPC Failure: UNIMPLEMENTED

Tags: java, hyperledger-fabric, hyperledger, ibm-blockchain

I've been trying to work with Hyperledger Fabric with IBM VSCode Plugin. Recently after I upgraded the plugin to support Hyperledger v2, the application stopped working with a few errors, and I'm having trouble understanding why these happen.

The first error I get is:

```
[main] ERROR org.hyperledger.fabric.sdk.ServiceDiscovery - Service discovery in channel: mychannel, peer: Peer{ id: 2, name: org1peer-api.127-0-0-1.nip.io:8080.......
```

which seems weird as it's declaring discovery which doesn't seem to be an error.

The second error I get is:

```
[main] ERROR org.hyperledger.fabric.sdk.Channel - Channel Channel{id: 1, name: mychannel} Sending proposal with transaction: ........gRPC failure=Status{code=UNIMPLEMENTED, description=HTTP status code 404
invalid content-type: text/plain; charset=utf-8
headers: Metadata(:status=404,content-type=text/plain; charset=utf-8,date=Mon, 01 Mar 2021 05:04:34 GMT,x-content-type-options=nosniff,content-length=19)
```

and on the blockchain console, I get a "proxy error, client disconnected" message.

which I also does not understand as I'm passing in the same arguments as I did before with HLF gateway & chain 1.4, like:

```
contract.submitTransaction("changeCarOwner", key, owner);
```

And the smart contract is correctly deployed on the BC too:

[IBM VSCo BC Console Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kd65i.png)

I'd be really grateful if someone can help me with this issue as I've been stuck for about a month now and cannot test my new application at all. Thanks in advance.